# How to detect if app has been installed for more than a day?

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the simplest way to detect if my app has been installed for more than a day? I'd like to use Kotlin.

Pseudo-code:

```
if(appInstalledForMoreThanADay)
{
    print("this app has been installed on this device for more than 1 day")
}
```

Comment: When it is first run store the install date (for example in shared preferences). But be aware, that the user can delete the application data which will reset the App to newly installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1796579/henry) mentioned, You can use shared preferences to save the date of installation, and then every time the app starts check if the current date is one day bigger than the saved date. It should look something like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    companion object
    {
        const val INSTALLATION_DATE_KEY = "INSTALLATION_DATE_KEY"
        const val MILLIS_IN_ONE_DAY = 86_400_000L;
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return

        val installationTime = sharedPref.getLong(INSTALLATION_DATE_KEY, -1L)

        if (installationTime == -1L) // app run for first time
        {
            with(sharedPref.edit()) {
                val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
                Log.d("MyTag", "First run. Time = $time")
                putLong(INSTALLATION_DATE_KEY, time)
                commit()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - MILLIS_IN_ONE_DAY >= installationTime)
            {
                Log.d("MyTag", "App installed more than one day ago")
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("MyTag", "App installed less than one day ago")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS. It won't be "installation" time but "first-run time". So when the user installs the app and runs it for the first time after 2 days it won't work.

Comment: I get error `'return' is not allowed here` on this line: `val sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return`

Comment: I used this code and everything was wroking. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#kotlin). Maybe try just `val sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Comment: I think the logic is wrong. I tried this `const val MILLIS_IN_ONE_DAY = 10000` to check if it can detect if the app has been installed for more than 10 seconds but it doesn't work. Please try it and tell what you think

Comment: Shouldn't be `if (installationTime + MILLIS_IN_ONE_DAY <= System.currentTimeMillis())` instead?

Comment: Yeah, You are right, my bad. It should be `System.currentTimeMillis() - MILLIS_IN_ONE_DAY >= installationTime`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the actual install time through `context.getPackageManager()` and grabbing the [`PackageInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo#firstInstallTime)

> `public long firstInstallTime`
>
> The time at which the app was first installed. Units are as per `System#currentTimeMillis()`

There's `lastUpdateTime` too if you're into that